Floating hybrid laminate floor to tile tranistion
There is already installed interlocking hybrid laminate flooring on kitchen side which is 6mm thick and 8mm thick procelain tile already glued to the laundry side of the floor. The gap between them is around variable from 38 to 40mm since end of laminate panel is not straight. So I couldn't figure out the best option to make smooth transition. The transition strip I was looking online to buy doesn't fits my requirement. Here I have image of the floor. 

Check flooring stores and some big box stores.  Most transitions are 1.65 to 2 inches wide which is 41.91 to 50.8 mm.  These will work to cover the gap.
